# Compress rows of data by summing values, if they have the same ID

Tags: r

What my data usually looks like when the AS 400 produced schedules

```
 df <- data.frame(
   Date = c(rep("Dec 4", 10)),
   Line = c(rep(1,7),rep(2,3)),
   Style = c(rep(24510,7),rep(18605,3)),
   Qty = c(1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2,1,3))
```

This is what I want my data to look like. If you notice, the rows with style number 24510, have no been compressed to one row, with a quantity of 10. Before there were 7 individual rows with different quantities.

```
 df_goal <- data.frame(
   Date_goal = c(rep("Dec 4", 2)),
   Line_goal = c(1,2), 
   Style_goal = c(24510,18605),
   Qty_goal = c(10,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df_goal<-df %>% 
            group_by(Date,Line, Style ) %>% 
            summarize(Qty=sum(Qty)) %>%
            rename(Date_Goal =Date, Line_Goal=Line, Style_Goal=Style, Qty_Goal= Qty)
```

Comment: no worries, somehow `Qty` was converted to `factor`. Anyhow, this is a dupe of an [tag:r-faq] so, not very important how the question/data is presented. It has just rewording value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a total-count, this one is the simplest:

```
plyr::count(df, vars=c('Date', 'Line', 'Style'), wt_var = 'Qty')
```

If you don't have the plyr-package yet, run `install.packages('plyr')` first.